# How to make text align to top of div and stay responsive?

Tags: html, css

I'm just trying to make a simple brochure that has text at the top of the page and just trying to make the header sit at the top of the page, and my h1 and h2 sit in the centre of the page. I know ( or think I know ) this has to do with collapsing margins but i cant seem to figure out how to write the css.

within the container class is just

```css
.container-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container container-flex'>
  <main class='steak-background'>
    <header> Mouthwateringly Delicious</header>
    <h1>Learn how to make <span>the best BBQ ribs</span> in town</h1>
    <h2> Join us for this live webinar</h2>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want h1,h2 sit in centre of the page and stay responsive.

`text-align:center;`will make text align center.

```css
.container-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<main class='steak-background'>
  <header> Mouthwateringly Delicious</header>
  <h1 class="center">Learn how to make <span>the best BBQ ribs</span> in town</h1>
  <h2 class="center"> Join us for this live webinar</h2>
</main>
```